# Mapping an XML Element value to array of elements in target XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, soa, xslt-grouping, oracle-soa

I have a requirement where I have an XML File like:

```
<main>
    <Qnumber>10</Qnumber>
    <Qaddress>hyderabad</Qaddress>
    <Qratio>12:3</Qratio>
    <QGet>Getthevalue</QGet>
</main>
```

These values are to be mapped to target schema in the following fashion:

We have a tag called which is of 1to many(1-infinite):

```
<Additional properties>
    <property>
        <Name></Name>
        <Value></Value>
    </property>
</Additional properties>
```

Now I have to map to this in the following way:

```
<Additional properties>
    <property>
        <Name>Qnumber</Name>
        <Value>10</Value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <Name>Qaddress</Name>
        <Value>hyderabad</Value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <Name>Qratio</Name>
        <Value>12:3</Value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <Name>QGet</Name>
        <Value>Getthevalue</Value>
    </property>
</Additional properties>
```

I have to this stuff in the XSLT.Can anyone help on this particular concept.
    Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot have space in the name of your XML element. Thus, I have replaced the space with `_` .

Here is a solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="main">
        <Additional_properties>
            <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 5">
                    <property>
                        <xsl:element name="Name">
                            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Value">
                            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                        </xsl:element> 
                    </property>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </Additional_properties>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you and This will work if all the values are to be taken into consideration and now The problem is i have say 5 more tags in xml like  <main>
    <Qnumber>10</Qnumber>
    <Qaddress>hyderabad</Qaddress>
    <Qratio>12:3</Qratio>
    <QGet>Getthevalue</QGet>
 <Qversion>1.0</Qversion>
 <QVariable>123</Qvariable>
 <QTag>456</QTag>
 <Qchange>1234</Qchange>
</main> So i want only the first 4 values to be in the additional properties.Can you help me on this.

Comment: You can check the values with `xsl:if`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this

Comment: I have updated my answer. Basically, you test whether the current node in the loop fits the condition. This will process only the first 4 nodes. If you, however, want to specify the names of the nodes instead, you can check for their names, not their position and use "or" in the test expression.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and can you tell me if i dont have the specified order like tags at different positions

Comment: Then you can do it like I explained in my earlier comment: `test="name()='Qnumber' or name()='Qaddress' or ..."`

Comment: ok then only one if condition and or for all the values   that needs to be passed into the property value is fine right

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again i dont know if i am placing match="main" i am getting error ----Error: <xsl:template match="/"> and <xsl:template name="..."> and what is the significance of the select="./*"

Comment: `.` is the current node. `*` is a wild card. i.e. that means select a node that is a child of the current node. Thus, the for-each loops through all the direct child nodes under the current node (which is "main", as this is what the template matches). If you are adding more to the XSLT and getting this error, I would advise you to ask a new question - with the XSLT you are using (all of it) and the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help will be remembered.Actually right now i am using / for the pattern match

Comment: HI Maria Deleva , i have added the new question in the link..can you please answer on that.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40787013/xslt-mapping-using-foreach

Comment: @ Maria DelevaCheck out the Question   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868419/convert-31-dec-2016-to-2016-12-31

Comment: @michael.hor257k can you please look at this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178098/xslt-to-concate-distinct-values-for-repeated-elements

Comment: can you please look at the question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178098/xslt-to-concate-distinct-values-for-repeated-elements