# XSLT Mapping using foreach

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, exslt

This is the sample XML data that i am using and then i have to pass all the values to an additional properties tag..

```
<ns1:Quote>
<ns1:QuoteVendor>123</ns1:QuoteVendor>
<ns1:QuoteNumber>sai</ns1:QuoteNumber>
<ns1:QuoteVersion>sri</ns1:QuoteVersion>
<ns1:QuoteValue>sas</ns1:QuoteValue>
<ns1:QuoteProperty>sandy</ns1:QuoteProperty>
</ns1:Quote>
```

After transformation using XSLT i am expecting the format as

```
<AdditionalProperties>
<ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Propertyname>QuoteVendor</ns1:Propertyname>
<ns1:propertyValue>123</ns1:propertyValue>
</ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Propertyname>QuoteNumber</ns1:Propertyname>
<ns1:propertyValue>sai</ns1:propertyValue>
</ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Propertyname>QuoteVersion</ns1:Propertyname>
<ns1:propertyValue>sri</ns1:propertyValue>
</ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Propertyname>QuoteValue</ns1:Propertyname>
<ns1:propertyValue>sas</ns1:propertyValue>
</ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Propertyname>QuoteProperty</ns1:Propertyname>
<ns1:propertyValue>sandy</ns1:propertyValue>
</ns1:Properties>
</AdditionalProperties>
```

The  transformation that i am using currently is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <?oracle-xsl-mapper
      <!-- SPECIFICATION OF MAP SOURCES AND TARGETS, DO NOT MODIFY. -->
      <mapSources>
        <source type="WSDL">
          <schema location="../BPELProcess1.wsdl"/>
          <rootElement name="Quote" namespace="http://www.example.org"/>
        </source>
      </mapSources>
      <mapTargets>
        <target type="WSDL">
          <schema location="../BPELProcess1.wsdl"/>
          <rootElement name="AdditionalProperties" namespace="http://www.example.org"/>
        </target>
      </mapTargets>
      <!-- GENERATED BY ORACLE XSL MAPPER 11.1.1.7.8(build 150622.2350.0222) AT [THU NOV 24 17:33:14 IST 2016]. -->
    ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                    xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/"
                    xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20"
                    xmlns:mhdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.mediator.service.common.functions.MediatorExtnFunction"
                    xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
                    xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org"
                    xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue"
                    xmlns:hwf="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/workflow/xpath"
                    xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:med="http://schemas.oracle.com/mediator/xpath"
                    xmlns:ids="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/services/IdentityService/xpath"
                    xmlns:bpm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn20/extensions"
                    xmlns:xdk="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension/xpath/function/xdk"
                    xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                    xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/add/MultiplevaluesTest/BPELProcess1"
                    xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension"
                    xmlns:socket="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.adapter.socket.ProtocolTranslator"
                    xmlns:ldap="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension/ldap"
                    exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl ns1 plnk xsd wsdl client bpws xp20 mhdr bpel oraext dvm hwf med ids bpm xdk xref ora socket ldap">
      <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns1:AdditionalProperties>
          <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:Quote/*">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="(position() = 1.0) or (position() = 3.0)">
                <ns1:Properties>
                  <ns1:Propertyname>
                    <xsl:value-of select='substring-after(name(),"ns1:")'/>
                  </ns1:Propertyname>
                  <ns1:propertyValue>
                    <xsl:value-of select='/ns1:Quote/*/text()'/>
                  </ns1:propertyValue>
                </ns1:Properties>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </ns1:AdditionalProperties>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Output after using this is

```
<AdditionalProperties>
<ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Propertyname>QuoteVendor</ns1:Propertyname>
<ns1:propertyValue>123</ns1:propertyValue>
</ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Properties>
<ns1:Propertyname>QuoteVersion</ns1:Propertyname>
<ns1:propertyValue>123</ns1:propertyValue>
</ns1:Properties>
</AdditionalProperties>
```

I am not getting the text value for the specific tag.The same element is repeated for all the values.
can anyone help me on this on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/ns1:Quote/*/text()` always select the text of the first child of `ns1:Quote`.

You can simply use `.` to get the value of the current node.

As [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev) points out in the comments:

> `text()` ... selects all text-node-children of the context node. Then the string-value of the first of these is used (in XPath 1.0, in XPath 2.0 this most often results in type error -- a sequence of nodes passed when a single node expected). If we know that there is a single text-node child, it is the shortest to use a dot -- `.`  which stands for the context node

In addition, instead of `substring-after(name(),"ns1:")`, you can simply use `local-name()`.

Comment: Local-name is working but still the value is same.Thanks

Comment: @srinivaskalyan did you change `/ns1:Quote/*/text()` to `text()`?

Comment: yes i do.But then if i close the transformation file it is coming back to /ns1:Quote/*/text()

Comment: try `select='current()/text()'`

Comment: Yes Maria,Working now.Thank you very much.and in the for-each value,i have given select="/ns1:Quote/*" when i am giving "./* " it is not happening.Can you tell me why?

Comment: @srinivaskalyan It seems that in this case `./*` matches the Quote tag, i.e., the `.` matches one level above the Quote tag. So, if you write it as `./*/*` it works. Sometimes, depending on the processor, there might be differences in what exactly the `./*` this matches. You can always experiment and check what happens.

Comment: please look at this Question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789475/xsd-for-the-xml-along-with-the-soap-headers

Comment: I have applied  ./*/* .It didnot work and no value.                                                         <Test>
<AdditionalProperties/>
</Test>

Comment: Thank you very much maria.It means alot.I felt very good as you kept on responding very fast for my queries. The Query is Working fine and your help means alot to me.Thank you very much.

Comment: Re: "You can simply use text() to get the value of the current node" -- actually this selects all text-node-children of the context node. Then the string-value of the first of these is used (in XPath 1.0, in XPath 2.0 this most often results in type error -- a sequence of nodes passed when a single node expected). If we know that there is a single text-node child, it is the shortest to use `.` .  Anyway, welcome to the scene of SO XPath / XSLT. Здравейте, Мария!