# Convert 31-DEC-2016 to 2016-12-31

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, exslt

I want to convert the 31-DEC-2016 i.e., dd-mmm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in the XSLT using format-dateTime function but the output is not as expected.Can anyone help on this?

```
<ns1:QuoteDate>
          <xsl:value-of select='concat(xp20:format-dateTime(/Quote/QuoteHeader/QuoteDate,"[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]"),"T00:00:00")'/>
        </ns1:QuoteDate>
```

I want to get the value for this particular thing.31-DEC-2016 : This is the input and i have to transform over here in the code

Once that is converted, How to concat the the value T00:00:00 to the date??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the `format-dateTime()` function on a string that is not a valid dateTime (or the `format-date()` function on a string that is not a valid date). You need to process the string using string functions first.

Try:

```
<xsl:template name="convertDate">
    <xsl:param name="datestring"/>

    <xsl:variable name="d" select="substring-before($datestring, '-')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="MMM" select="substring-before(substring-after($datestring, '-'), '-')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="string-length(substring-before('JANFEBMARAPRMAYJUNJULAUGSEPOCTNOVDEC', $MMM)) div 3 + 1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="y" select="substring-after(substring-after($datestring, '-'), '-')"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$y"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($m, '-00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '-00')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Calling this template with a datestring parameter of "31-DEC-2016" will return a value of "2016-12-31".

---

Example of call (mostly guessing, not having seen the input):

```
<ns1:QuoteDate>
    <xsl:call-template name="convertDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="datestring" select="/Quote/QuoteHeader/QuoteDate"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</ns1:QuoteDate>
```

---

---

In XSLT 2.0, you can define a function instead of a named template. The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:function name="my:convertDate">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="parts" select="tokenize($string, '-')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="index-of (('JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'), $parts[2])"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="xs:date(concat($parts[3], format-number($m, '-00'), format-number(number($parts[1]), '-00')))" />
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="my:convertDate('9-MAR-2016')"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>2016-03-09</result>
```

Comment: How to use this template in my xslt? i want to apply this template for a particular variable

Comment: @srinivaskalyan Please edit your question and provide an example - see [mcve].

Comment: This is happening fine thank you but one small help. The service accepts only the datetime format.So once the date is available with the above template how to append the Time to it?

Comment: @srinivaskalyan Just add `<xsl:text>T00:00:00</xsl:text>`.

Comment: I want to add the text to the same date that i have got from the template           <ns1:QuoteDate>
    <xsl:call-template name="convertDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="datestring" select="/Quote/QuoteHeader/QuoteDate"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</ns1:QuoteDate>

Comment: @srinivaskalyan You can add it after `</xsl:call-template>`. Or you can add it as part of the template, at the end, after `<xsl:value-of select="format-number($d, '-00')"/>`.

Comment: It is not appending the T00:00:00 to the date at the end if i am using the text after call template. Is there any another way to append the time to the date that is coming from the template

Comment: If your code doesn't work then you need to debug it, not look for a different way of tackling the problem.

Comment: @srinivaskalyan See a working demo here: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Ef

Comment: @srinivaskalyan Is your question not answered?

Comment: Yes..Thank you very much

Comment: @michael.hor257k can you look at this--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935863/looping-element-to-single-element-in-xslt?noredirect=1#comment69085669_40935863

Answer (score -1):

If you're formatting only dates, I could suggest

format-date(date, format)

Maybe this can help you,

http://www.sixtree.com.au/articles/2013/formatting-dates-and-times-using-xslt-2.0-and-xpath/

Comment: Thank you but in SOA when i use this function i am getting some error.