# Is it possible to format a big decimal to date in xslt

Tags: java, xml, date, xslt

I am getting date in xml from xslt as below:

```
<DATE>20161211000000</DATE>
```

I want to format this to valid date format as 11 Dec 2016.

So is it possible to format the date inside xslt?

Please help.

Comment: Can you use XSLT2.0?

Comment: I am using XSLT1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="DATE">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 7, 2)" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring(., 5, 2)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="substring('JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec', 3 * ($month - 1) + 1, 3)"/>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 4)" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your code, it worked. Can u please tell me if I need to change the format say Dec 11, 2016 like this. How would I do ?

Comment: I think the code is clear enough for you to make this adjustment on your own.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried and its coming fine. But need to ask one thing, is it possible to add this template to two different nodes. I mean I don't want to copy the same logic again n again for two diff nodes. It will be a great help.

Comment: Yes, you can make it a named template and call it as necessary. See a similar example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868419/convert-31-dec-2016-to-2016-12-31/40868916#40868916

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a big decimal but rather an element with some value representing a date in a format not supported in XSLT, so you would need to convert that into an XSLT 2.0 `xs:date` value which you can then format with `format-date` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#date-time-examples):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="DATE">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="
                    format-date(xs:date(
                    concat(substring(., 1, 4), '-', substring(., 5, 2), '-', substring(., 7, 2))), '[D01] [MN,*-3] [Y0001]')"
            />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```