# Concatination date with apostrophe in xslt 1.0?

Tags: date, append, xslt-1.0, concatenation, apostrophe

I would like to concatenate date with apostrophe. Like

if 
date = 2017-05-04
then output should be = '2017-05-04'

I tried the below but I didn't get proper answer

```
<xsl:variable name="apostrophe">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="date" select="2017-05-04"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($apostrophe,$date,$apostrophe)"/>
```

But the output was : '2008'
I need output like : '2017-05-04'

If I declare date like below

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="'2017-05-04'"/>
```

problem is solved. But I am getting date from elsewhere it is in 2017-05-04 format.

Request someone to help on this.

Comment: "*But the output was : '2018'*" I don't think so. The output was `2008` because your variable contains an arithmetic expression and  `2017 - 5 - 4 = 2008`.   -- "*But I am getting date from elsewhere*" Well, how exactly?

Comment: Hi Michael, Yes output is 2008. It was a typo. I am getting date from a xml which is in this format 01-Feb-2017.I need to convert this and pass it as '2017-02-01'.

Comment: Please add an example of the XML to your question. Also, if it's formatted as `01-Feb-2017` then why do you say that "*it is in 2017-05-04 format*"?

Comment: See here how to reformat a date like yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868419/convert-31-dec-2016-to-2016-12-31/40868916#40868916

Comment: Hi Michael, I am converting 01-Feb-2017 to 2017-02-01 somewhere in the code. After converting I need to pass '2017-02-01' as parameter. Anyway I resolved this issue now and I did that when I am converting 01-Feb-2017 to '2017-02-01' instead of 2017-02-01.