# XSLT to concate distinct values for repeated elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a requirement where i will be getting the XML as follows:

```
<Input>
    <Record>
        <EMPID>FirstEmployee</EMPID>
    </Record>           
    <Record>
        <EMPID>SecondEmployee</EMPID>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EMPID>FirstEmployee</EMPID>
    </Record>           
    <Record>
        <EMPID>SecondEmployee</EMPID>
    </Record>
</Input>
```

My expected output for the xml above after applying transformation is:

```
<Output>
    <Record>
        <EMPID>FirstEmployee|1</EMPID>
    </Record>
    <Record>
         <EMPID>SecondEmployee|1</EMPID>
    </Record>
    <Record>
         <EMPID>FirstEmployee|2</EMPID>
    </Record>
    <Record>
         <EMPID>SecondEmployee|2</EMPID>
    </Record>
</Output>
```

When used one of the solutions in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?oracle-xsl-mapper
  <!-- SPECIFICATION OF MAP SOURCES AND TARGETS, DO NOT MODIFY. -->
  <mapSources>
    <source type="WSDL">
      <schema location="../BPELProcess1.wsdl"/>
      <rootElement name="Input" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/UMSAdapterVerify/XSLTCheck/BPELProcess1"/>
    </source>
  </mapSources>
  <mapTargets>
    <target type="WSDL">
      <schema location="../BPELProcess1.wsdl"/>
      <rootElement name="Output" namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/UMSAdapterVerify/XSLTCheck/BPELProcess1"/>
    </target>
  </mapTargets>
  <!-- GENERATED BY ORACLE XSL MAPPER 11.1.1.7.8(build 150622.2350.0222) AT [FRI DEC 16 15:55:29 IST 2016]. -->
?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/"
    xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20"
    xmlns:mhdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.mediator.service.common.functions.MediatorExtnFunction"
    xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
    xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/UMSAdapterVerify/XSLTCheck/BPELProcess1"
    xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue"
    xmlns:hwf="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/workflow/xpath"
    xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:med="http://schemas.oracle.com/mediator/xpath"
    xmlns:ids="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/services/IdentityService/xpath"
    xmlns:bpm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn20/extensions"
    xmlns:xdk="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension/xpath/function/xdk"
    xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension"
    xmlns:socket="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.adapter.socket.ProtocolTranslator"
    xmlns:ldap="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension/ldap"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl client plnk xsd wsdl bpws xp20 mhdr bpel oraext dvm hwf med ids bpm xdk xref ora socket ldap">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <client:Output>
      <xsl:for-each select="/client:Input/client:Record">
        <client:Record>
          <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
          <xsl:variable name="pos">
            <xsl:number level="any" count="client:EMPID[.=$current]"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <client:EMPID>
            <xsl:value-of select='concat(.,"|",$pos)'/>
          </client:EMPID>
        </client:Record>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </client:Output>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is

```
<Output>
    <client:Record>
        <client:EMPID> Srinivas |0</client:EMPID>
    </client:Record>
    <client:Record>
        <client:EMPID> kalyan |0</client:EMPID>
    </client:Record>
    <client:Record>
        <client:EMPID> Srinivas |0</client:EMPID>
    </client:Record>
    <client:Record>
        <client:EMPID> kalyan |0</client:EMPID>
    </client:Record>
</Output>
```

Can anyone help on this

Comment: There is no Line 38 (or 42 or 44) in my code.

Comment: I have updated the Question.Please look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an option that uses [xsl:number](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number)...

**XML Input**

```
<Input>
    <Record>
        <EMPID>FirstEmployee</EMPID>
    </Record>           
    <Record>
        <EMPID>SecondEmployee</EMPID>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EMPID>FirstEmployee</EMPID>
    </Record>           
    <Record>
        <EMPID>SecondEmployee</EMPID>
    </Record>
</Input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Input">
    <Output>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Output>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EMPID">
    <xsl:variable name="current" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="pos">
      <xsl:number level="any" count="EMPID[.=$current]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,'|',$pos)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Output>
   <Record>
      <EMPID>FirstEmployee|1</EMPID>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <EMPID>SecondEmployee|1</EMPID>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <EMPID>FirstEmployee|2</EMPID>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <EMPID>SecondEmployee|2</EMPID>
   </Record>
</Output>
```

---

**Edit for updated question...**

Your `xsl:for-each` is selecting `client:Record`, so you need to update the `current` variable to select the child `client:EMPID`. You should also count the `client:Record` elements instead of `client:EMPID`.

**Example**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <client:Output>
    <xsl:for-each select="client:Input/client:Record">
      <client:Record>
        <xsl:variable name="current" select="client:EMPID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="pos">
          <xsl:number level="any" count="client:Record[client:EMPID=$current]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <client:EMPID>
          <xsl:value-of select='concat(.,"|",$pos)'/>
        </client:EMPID>
      </client:Record>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </client:Output>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have updated the question.I have used your approach but the value is not getting reflected.

Comment: @srinivaskalyan - Please see the update in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EMPID">
    <xsl:variable name="varPresentValue"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '|', count(preceding::EMPID[.=$varPresentValue])+1)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Input">
    <Output><xsl:apply-templates/></Output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is *distinct* values, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Input">
    <Output>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EMPID">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id()"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is much more efficient than repeatedly counting preceding sibling or numbering similar nodes.

Comment: @srinivaskalyan Your question is tagged `XSLT` and the above works in XSLT: http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5En. if you are using a non-conforming processor, or adding my code to yours, I am not interested.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k ... I will be using the transform activity in Oracle SOA actually. The copy apply template are not working in here.I will try to use your idea and try to implement it here.